# Encrypted phone no longer asks for pattern when turning on?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, security, nexus-6

Nexus 6 running stock 5.0.1 not rooted. It used to ask me for my pattern every time I turned it on from a powered off state. Now it seems to boot fully without asking. Under Settings > Security it still claims to be Encrypted and tapping the option does nothing.

Would upgrading from 5.0 to 5.0.1 change this behavior? Am I still secure?

Would this behavior stop if I add my Android Wear watch as a trusted device?

Comment: FYI, there's a bug report about this issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79309).

Comment: Whilst this post is old, this happened to me on 6.0.1. The option to reenable a password on boot is now inside the password change menu in settings. Thanks for the heads up to look in this area as I was a bit annoyed that my encrypted phone was decrypting itself after I used an accessibility service, once!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have since figured out my own answer. I can reproduce it with the following process:

1) Settings > Security > Screen lock > put in current pattern > Select Pattern > Note that "Require pattern to start device" is checked

2) Make no changes and back out to Settings (or press home and re-open Settings)

3) Go to Accessibility

4) Turn on any Accessibility Service (I turned on Pushbullet but it doesn't seem to matter what service you do)

5) Follow step 1  until you see that "Require pattern to start device" is unchecked.

In the Android M Preview 2, turning on Push Bullet prompted me with "If you turn on Pushbullet, your device won't use your screen lock to enhance data encryption" and pressing ok brought me to a screen where I needed to enter my current pattern. The text reads "Because turning on Pushbullet affects data encryption, you need to confirm your pattern." I do not remember this screen in 5.0 or 5.0.1 but I believe this is what was causing it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in Android; at some point asking for credentials at boot has been disabled. You can re-enable this by changing your password/pin (you can "change" it to the same one you're currently using, too).